# Simple MYSQL wont echo :( mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql, web

i would love if any one could help me out with this issue.

The config.php file which is included works fine, and the database loads fine.

It's just about echoing stuff out of the database when connected with an Included file.
How would i do that the simplest cleanest way?

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$username = $_COOKIE["ava_username"];
$user_id = $_COOKIE["ava_userid"];
$useridquery = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM ava_users WHERE username=$cookie");

if (isset($_COOKIE["ava_username"])) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM ava_users WHERE username=$username");
        echo "Cookie is enabled, and User status login is 0<br>";
        echo "User ID: ". $user_id . "<br>";
        echo "User Name: " . $_COOKIE["ava_username"]. "<br>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        echo $row['points'] . " and Joined " . $row['joined'];
        echo "<br>";
  }


}      
?>
```

Comment: how can we help without looking your code ?

Comment: where is the script ?

Comment: Added the script, sorry guys.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injections; you should read on [how to prevent them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: @user3370305 are using mysql or mysqli ?

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed up `mysql_*` with `mysql_i*`

```
$useridquery = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM ava_users WHERE username=$cookie");
```

above line contains wrong query (need to use quotation  )and seems that `$useridquery` is unused. this line should be like this:

```
$useridquery = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM ava_users WHERE username='$cookie'");
```

same wrong query in this line :

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM ava_users WHERE username=$username");
```

should be :

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT points FROM ava_users WHERE username='$username'");
```

try this:

```
include 'config.php';
$username = $_COOKIE["ava_username"];
$user_id = $_COOKIE["ava_userid"];
$useridquery = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM ava_users WHERE username='$cookie'"); //add quotation in  variable 

if (isset($_COOKIE["ava_username"])) {
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT points FROM ava_users WHERE username='$username'"); //add quotation in username variable 
        echo "Cookie is enabled, and User status login is 0<br>";
        echo "User ID: ". $user_id . "<br>";
        echo "User Name: " . $_COOKIE["ava_username"]. "<br>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        echo $row['points'] . " and Joined " . $row['joined'];
        echo "<br>";
  }


}
```

Comment: @user3370305 : did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing between `mysql` and `mysqli` .

Try this:

```
 <?php
include 'config.php';
$username = $_COOKIE["ava_username"];
$user_id = $_COOKIE["ava_userid"];
$useridquery = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM ava_users WHERE username=$cookie");

if (isset($_COOKIE["ava_username"])) {
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT points FROM ava_users WHERE username=$username");
    echo "Cookie is enabled, and User status login is 0<br>";
    echo "User ID: ". $user_id . "<br>";
    echo "User Name: " . $_COOKIE["ava_username"]. "<br>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo $row['points'] . " and Joined " . $row['joined'];
    echo "<br>";
 }


}      
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing functions from the `mysql` library with functions from the `mysqli`. They aren't the same, and that won't work. Please [don't use `mysql_*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

Another problem: you use `$cookie` in your first query, but it looks like you mean `$username`. `$cookie` isn't defined. It doesn't look like you ever even use that query's results, though, so you could just take it out.

Another problem: you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: He doesn’t even use `$useridquery`.

Comment: I know, and I point that out above. I did edit my answer, but that was there before you posted your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are mixing two libraries (the mysql_*-family and the mysqli_*-family). You cannot use `mysqli_fetch_array(...)` with `mysql_query(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the mysqli_query will not work till both the parameters are included. Mysqli query requires 2 parameters $link = connection to the database and $sql = the sql query. So typically the mysqli_query is of the following format `mysqli_query($link, $sql)` . You can try as below

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
global $link; //where $link = mysqli_connect("DBserver", "DBuser", "DBpswd", "DBname")

$username = $_COOKIE["ava_username"];
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
$user_id = $_COOKIE["ava_userid"];
//if the id is an integer then instead of mysqli_real_escape_string use
$user_id = intval($user_id);

$sql = "SELECT id FROM ava_users WHERE username = '$username'";
$useridquery = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (isset($_COOKIE["ava_username"])) {
$sql = "SELECT points FROM ava_users WHERE username='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
echo "Cookie is enabled, and User status login is 0<br>";
echo "User ID: ". $user_id . "<br>";
echo "User Name: " . $_COOKIE["ava_username"]. "<br>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['points'] . " and Joined " . $row['joined'];
echo "<br>";
 }


}      
?>
```

However even this code is highly vulnerable to MYSQL injection. You should always use parameterized queries to get protection against sql injection.